# ASP.NET MVC 2: "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

All of a sudden, I'm getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'WnvHtmlConvertDemo' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

But I've since removed any trace of using this DLL and any references... yet I'm still getting this error!

Is there some mysterious place that the project is looking for this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS wasn't reflecting the changes. I had to delete my local version of the project and get the project again from TFS. Stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Clean solution" in VS2010. And then rebuild your project.

Comment: try to delete all files from `bin`, `obj` folders of your project

Comment: if it wouldn't help run Ctrl+Shift+F - search entire solution with `*.*` file mask using as search query your assembly name 'WnvHtmlConvertDemo'

Comment: It was TFS. I had to wipe my local files and re-get latest.